# Jquery Calendar and how to setup a connected booking calendar with two input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, calendar

When it comes to a booking calendar with a start and end-date, I think http://www.swiss.com (choose two Airports, click on search and you will see the date fields) has the **perfect** execution.

It basically works like this:
There are two input fields for outbound flight and return flight. If you click in either one of those, two calendar pop up. One under each input field.

They will stay open if you choose a date in the first calendar and only close if you select a date in the second calendar.

In the mobile view - where there isn't much space - only one calendar opens and the second opens when you choose a date from the first one.

I think this is a much better solution than having one large input field only and sort of a 3-month calendar to choose start and end, which seems to be the most used option for these kind of setups.

---

I figured I'd use the Jquery Datepicker: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML as it seems it's powerful and easy to style. But I cannot find a way to keep the datepicker open and only close it when the second datepicker has a date chosen. The documentation seems not to mention it, and even with all the demos on the page, this particular problem isn't addressed.

If someone knows a solution to mentioned setup, I'd be really glad to get some pointers. I'd also switch to another calendar plugin if there is one in which this is easy to implement.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use http://bevacqua.github.io/rome/ because it has a really nice API: https://github.com/bevacqua/rome - there you should take a look at show(), hide() and the autoClose setting.

Comment: I like a lot on this datepicker, but it cannot select a range as far as I see it :(

Comment: If you look at the demos: http://bevacqua.github.io/rome/ there is an example called "Range between two inputs? Sure!" which shows a functionality that is close to the one on the Swiss website. You just have to disable the auto-close on the first element.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and try to use it. I have however quite some trouble with that calendar. How can I catch events?

I tried 
------------------------------------------------------
$(function(){
   var cals = rome(left, {
    dateValidator: rome.val.beforeEq(right),
    time: false,
    inputFormat: "DD.MM.YYYY",
    min: "23.11.2015"   
    });

   cals.on('data', (show) => {
           console.log("opened");
   });  
});
------------------------------------------------------

But I only get an "opened" after I close the calendar....

Comment: Here is a fiddle: I tried https://jsfiddle.net/Khardan1/5xm8d2pL/

Comment: Och, my bad, I have it: https://jsfiddle.net/Khardan1/5xm8d2pL/1/

Comment: Do you maybe know any way I can prevent Rome from switching the date when a month gets switched?

As soon as I switch a month it automatically switches the day to this new month (eg. 28. November to 28. January). That prevents me from doing all kind of things...

Comment: I've looked at the API and couldn't find a easy way to do this, I guess the best thing would be to change it in the source - if you look at the source here: https://github.com/bevacqua/rome/blob/master/src/calendar.js, you find the updateCalendar method. It seems like there is already an opened issue about this: https://github.com/bevacqua/rome/issues/138

Comment: I did it, it's now exactly as I wanted it, but was quite a piece of work!

Needed to deactivate "api.emitValues();" in the function invalidateInput and set update(true) in changeMonth.